# Install-less python web app on headless CentOS 5.x-6.x

Tags: python, web-applications, installation

I have a Linux web application which installs a webserver, a database, digital certificates etc using a set of `.sh` scripts.

In order to simplify user interaction during installation such as entering passwords, certificate details and such, I want to create a GUI installer. After much deliberation, following are some decisions and related questions

1. The target systems may or may not have a Desktop or a monitor installed. So providing a web interface to the install process may be the way to go. User would copy the application to the target machine, start the webservice which would then expose a web interface to continue the install. **Would Python be a good choice for this?**
2. Since this is an installer itself, the requirements to run it must be practically nil. This requires

   - Use python's built in `SimpleHTTPServer`. This will be used the one time during installation and then be killed. **Any caveats to using the default python web server?**
   - Compile app into standalone binary using one of the Freezing utilities. We don't want to depend on the user having python on their system  and have been asked to account for admins who've removed python due to whatever reason. **Is this precaution necessary?**

Any comments on the general approach or alternative options will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not provide a virtual appliance? This way you control everything installed on it. It sounds like your application is pretty self contained anyway.

Comment: We do plan move to virtual appliances in the future. But this current method must be implemented for the first release due to a variety of logistical reasons.